# Referring to the contents of c++ temporary strings

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, temporaries

Following code is working and I am trying to understand how.

```
int Process::processTextFile(const boost::filesystem::path& infile)
{
    const char *file = infile.string().c_str();
    uint16_t num_lines = 0;
    .
    .
    .
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(file, "r");
    .
    .
    //Use fp for reading and stuff.
}
```

From what I understand `infile.string()` creates a temporary and file points to the contents. Moment the statement ends (;) the temporary string should go out of scope leading to file being a dangling pointer.

I will be using string instead of `char*` but still need to understand what I am missing.

Compiler - gcc 4.8.4
Optimization - O3

Comment: You may be *lucky* if no other local variables are created after the line that calls `c_str()` and before using `const char* file`. The content of that temporary string may still exist in memory but you have no guarantees for that. Conclusion: it's undefined behaviour, **don't do this**.

Comment: @zett42 . Updated my question. There are local variables created after file. This code has been in use for a very long and has not failed AFAIK. If I had a penny each time I got lucky, by now I would have been the richest man on earth. :) Just want to make sure there are no gaps in my understanding.

Answer (score 2):

`infile.string()` returns an object of type `std::string`. And `.c_str()` returns a pointer to some content of the object, so `file` is a pointer to the content of the object. But at the end of the statement the `std::string` object and its content gets destructed. As result, the pointer `file` points to nowhere, at the begin of the next statement.

Answer (score -3):

C++ specifies that binding a temporary object to a reference to const on the stack lengthens the lifetime of the temporary to the lifetime of the reference itself, which means of **const char *file** which lies in the stack.

This C++ mechanism avoid what you pointed as dangling-reference error.
In the code above, the temporary lives until the closing curly brace of your funtion processTextFile.

You can check this [GOTW](https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/) for more info.

Comment: There is no const reference in the code, and no lifetime extension. The pointer *is* dangling.

Comment: @Quentin: Wrong. Pointer is not dangling, I just run a memcheck on the code above and there is no memory error detected.

Comment: [See for yourself](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e715101a0bb0c38d).

Comment: There's no reference declared to do a lifetime extension! That would look like `std::string&& file = infile.string();`